# angular directive to call UI Bootsrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make a directive to call a modal (with bootstrap-ui) to update some properties. the modal content would be different depending on where it's called from.

**updated**

I made a plunker to illustrate this (updated and working thanks to moderndegree's contribution)

now, is it possible to externalize the html code of the modal from the html file and to put the modal controller functions inside the  directive, so it would be possible to call it from different templates ?

Comment: Have you already tried the modules for angular around there like angular ui? You've problems if you're trying to carry IE8< with your app but even so it's easier to write it all from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first part of your question:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lQZfWO?p=preview

Comment: thank you, it's working. is it possible to externalize the html code of the modal (inside the directive), so i could call the <update> directive from different templates ?

Comment: Please leave a comment if you are going to downvote. @desgnl stated that my contribution was helpful.

Comment: could you help me on this one please ? I don't know how to put everything inside the directive. thank you